# CSV Serde format in Hive for different value types in table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hive-serde

A CSV file contain survey of user in below messy format and contain many different data types as string, int, range.

> China, 20-30, Male, xxxxx, yyyyy, Mobile Developer; zzzz-vvvv; "$40,000-50,000", Consulting
>
> Japan, 30-40, Female, xxxxx,     , Software Developer, zzzz-vvvv; "$40,000-50,000", Development
>
> . . . . .

The below code is used to convert the CSV file to a Hive table with each column assigned their respective values correctly.

```
add jar /home/cloudera/Desktop/project/csv-serde-1.1.2.jar;
drop table if exists 2016table;

create external table 2016table
(
  Country string,
  Age string,
  Gender string,
  Random1 string,
  Random2 string,
  Occupation string,
  Random3 string,
  Salary string,
  Industry string,
 )

 ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
 WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "separatorChar" = ",",
  "quoteChar"     = "\"",
  "escapeChar"    = "\\"
 )     
 STORED AS TEXTFILE;

 LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH "/home/cloudera/survey/2016edited.csv" INTO TABLE 2016table;
```

This code worked fine and each column got allocated separately with their values. All Select Queries give true result.

Now when trying to create another table("2016sort") from the upper table("2016table") with less coulmns the values are getting mixed in different columns.

Code used for that

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 2016sort;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE 2016sort (
 country1 string,
 age1 string,
 gender1 string,
 occupation1 string,
 salary1 string,
)

 ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
 WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
 "separatorChar" = ",",
 "quoteChar"     = "\"",
 "escapeChar"    = "\\" 
)     
STORED AS TEXTFILE;

insert into table 2016sort select country,age,gender,occupation,salary from 2016table;
```

But this code mess up values.
SELECT gender1 from 2016sort give mix values of gender column along with values of other column.

Can anyone help me figure out what is missing !

Comment: Columns names in both the tables should be same for insert and select, not sure if you have the different column names in just the example or not.

Comment: @roh they are same as that in table. The problem occur when filtering data from one hive table to another. It's messing up the empty spaces

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use csv serde for creating '2016sort'.
Because, it's not getting loaded from the .csv file. You are inserting into it by reading from the first one '2016table' which have already used csv serde to load itself from .csv file.

And querying from '2016table', will give plain text as resultant not in quoted form.